# Update MongoDB field using value of another field in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

In MongoDB PHP, is it possible to update the value of a field using the value from another field?

The below Mongo Shell Command is working fine. Value of a field `"product_name"` is updating to the field `"product_name_copy"`.

```
db.products.update(
  {},
  [{ $set: {
    "product_name_copy": "$product_name"
  }}],
  { multi: true }
)
```

But, While Am using this code in PHP,
***PHP code :***

```
$where = array();
$update = array('$set' => array("product_name_copy" => "$product_name"));
$options = array("multi" => true);
$bulkWrite = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$bulkWrite->update($where,$update,$options);
$updated    = $mongo->executeBulkWrite("$db_name.products", $bulkWrite);
```

Am getting this error

> Notice: Undefined variable: product_name in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\mongo\mongo-update.php on line 10

If I used single quotes instead of double quotes,

```
$update = array('$set' => array("product_name_copy" => '$product_name'));
```

the same value $product_name is updating to the field **"product_name_copy"** like below.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("602a291f0406011059006c15"),
        "product_id" : 15,
        "product_name" : "Test Product",
        "product_name_copy" : "$product_name"
}
```

Anyone know the solution for this problem.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

We need to put **'$set'** array into another one array for ***field value update.***

***PHP Code :***

```
$where = array();
$update = array(array('$set' => array("product_name_copy" => '$product_name')));
$options = array("multi" => true);
$bulkWrite = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$bulkWrite->update($where,$update,$options);
$updated    = $mongo->executeBulkWrite("$db_name.products", $bulkWrite);
```

Output of the above code is

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("602a291f0406011059006c15"),
        "product_id" : 15,
        "product_name" : "Test Product",
        "product_name_copy" : "Test Product"
}
```

This is what I exactly wanted.